# ECR login From Jenkins returns BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to login to ECR using Jenkins pipeline using the command shown in AWS

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <region-id> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region-id>.amazonaws.com
```

When I use it inside the bash container it works "Login Succeeded", Instead using it within the pipeline

```
sh "command"
```

Unfortunately, it returns

[image]

PS: I do have the last version of AWSCLI installed, Please can someone help

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
You can do use **docker.withRegistry** in your Jenkinsfile to login into ECR.

- Save aws credential as username password in Jenkins with some ID lets say "aws_credential" and use below in your pipeline

```
docker.withRegistry('https://$<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region-id>.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:<region-id>:aws_credential') {
                        // do something after login
                        } // withRegistry
```

**Option 2**:  Instead of login using Jenkins pipeline you can use cron to login daily or after reboot using below

```
@reboot aws ecr get-login-password --region <region-id> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region-id>.amazonaws.com
01 01 * * * aws ecr get-login-password --region <region-id> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region-id>.amazonaws.com
```

I personally opt for **Option 2**

Comment: If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left of this answer.